# Kotlin data class with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this data class in the backend written in Kotlin:

```
data class UpdateExample(
  val failures: List<ErrorDto> = emptyList()
)

data class ErrorDto(val errorCode: String)
```

In the frontend in TypeScript I use a hook that returns me this data class UpdateExample. I want to write the following

```
if(updateExample?.data?.failures[0] === "ruleError") return true
```

And of course this gives me the error “This condition will always return 'false' since the types '{ errorCode: string; }' and 'string' have no overlap”. How can I write something like

```
if(updateExample?.data?.failures[0] === ErrorDto("ruleError")) return true
```

in TypeScript?

Comment: `if(updateExample?.data?.failures[0].errorCode === "ruleError")`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `errorCode` property:

```ts
if(updateExample?.data?.failures[0].errorCode === "ruleError") return true
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```